# Reactjs file uploading with progress bar of each file uploads and cancel upload options

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, duplicates, progress-bar

I'm creating a module in reactjs application that upload files with the progress bar of file uploads. I'm showing the file upload progress using createPortal ,so that even if I navigate to a different page, it will still show and completes the upload process. I'm getting the progress of file uploads from the axios request options argument passed and updating the progress state of each file.

But my problem here is

1. Before completing the file uploading if I try to upload next set of images, my first set progress bar will disappear(though it uploads in background and shows the results later).
2. Also if I add the second set of files, sometimes duplicate files gets uploaded from the first set again.

To solve the above cases, I added the files list to a state and this state will gets updated when the next set comes.(Again here the second issue comes again). So what I did is when a file completes it's uploads and progress reaches 100%, I removed that file object from my state(files). This solved the problem of duplicate file uploads. Now a new problem came, since I'm updating the state everytime when a file completes the uploads, my createPortal component became unstable and it's flickering with each state change.

How can I solve this problem.